# How to extract fixed effects part of summary from lme4?

Tags: r, lme4

I wish to extract the fixed effects part of `summary()` as a data.frame. I am using `lme4` to run the following model:

```
SleepStudy <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
summary(SleepStudy)
```

I know that I can extract the random effects section of `summary` by using the following:

```
SleepStudy_RE <- as.data.frame(VarCorr(SleepStudy))
```

Is there a similar line of code for the fixed effects, including the estimate, standard error, degrees of freedom and exact p-value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`coef(summary(fitted_model))` should do it.

```
library(lme4)
SleepStudy <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
coef(summary(SleepStudy))
##              Estimate Std. Error  t value
## (Intercept) 251.40510  9.7467163 25.79383
## Days         10.46729  0.8042214 13.01543
```

If you want p-values you need `lmerTest` (you need to re-fit the model):

```
library(lmerTest)
SleepStudy <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
coef(summary(SleepStudy))
##              Estimate Std. Error       df  t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept) 251.40510  9.7467163  22.8102 25.79383        0
## Days         10.46729  0.8042214 161.0036 13.01543        0
```

I don't know why the p-values are *exactly* zero in this case; maybe something to take up with the `lmerTest` maintainers.

(As of April 10 2023 `lmerTest` returns the correct/unrounded p-values (2.2e-18 and 6.41e-27) ...)

You may also be interested in the [broom.mixed package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom.mixed/index.html).

Comment: Is it "_exactly_" zero because of rounding? `dt(26, 22)` yields `2.135502e-18`? I've saw that before with `lmer`. I know small P-values are hard to estimate.

Comment: Thank you, I need exact p-values so I can calculate confidence limits and then magnitudes of effect. Wow, I had never seen the `broom` package before! Fantastic!

Comment: 2.0e-18 is below `.Machine$double.eps` (smallest value such that 1.0+x != 1.0), but way above `.Machine$double.xmin` (smallest value such that x != 0) ...

Comment: internally `lmerTest` appears to use `2*(1 - pt(abs(resultTtest[i,2]), df = resultTtest[i,1]))` when they should use `2*pt(abs(resultTtest[i,2]), df = resultTtest[i,1], lower.tail=FALSE)` for precisely this reason. Again, probably worth an e-mail to the package maintainer.

Comment: ... of course in this case it's not that hard to just recalculate the p-values yourself using the correct incantation ...